# How to split file input into 2 different arrays java

Tags: java, arrays, file-io, phonebook

How do I split a file input text into 2 different array? I want to make n array for the names, and an array for the phone numbers. I managed to do the file input, but ive tried everything and cant seem to split the names and the numbers, then put it into 2 different arrays. Im noob pls help

here is how the phonebook.txt file looks like

Bin Arry,1110001111
Alex Cadel,8943257000
Poh Caimon,3247129843
Diego Amezquita,1001010000
Tai Mai Shu,7776665555
Yo Madow,1110002233
Caup Sul,5252521551
This Guy,7776663333
Me And I,0009991221
Justin Thyme,1113332222
Hey Oh,3939399339
Free Man,4533819911
Peter Piper,6480013966
William Mulock,9059671045

below is my code

```
   import java.io.*;
   import java.util.Scanner;
   import java.io.FileInputStream;
   import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
   import java.io.IOException;
   import java.io.InputStreamReader;
   import java.io.BufferedReader;
   public class demos {
   public static void main(String[]  args){

    FileInputStream Phonebook;  
    DataInputStream In;
    int i = 0;

     String fileInput;  
      try  
      { 

            Phonebook = new FileInputStream("phonebook.txt"); 

            FileReader fr = new FileReader("phonebook.txt");
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
            String buffer;
            String fulltext="";
            while ((buffer = br.readLine()) != null) {

                fulltext += buffer;

               // System.out.println(buffer);

                String names = buffer;
                char [] Y ; 
                Y = names.toCharArray();
                System.out.println(Y);

      }}
         catch (FileNotFoundException e)  
            { 
            System.out.println("Error - this file does not exist"); 
         }  
        catch (IOException e)   
        { 
            System.out.println("error=" + e.toString() ); 

         }
```

Comment: while you have next line save string splitted in array. first element goes into first list, second goes into second list. For splitting string https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/split-string-java-examples/

Answer (score 1):

You could simplify it if you are using Java 8:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Test {
    static ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
    static ArrayList<String> numbers = new ArrayList<String>();

    /**
     * For each line, split it on the comma and send to splitNameAndNum()
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Files.lines(new File("L:\\phonebook.txt").toPath())
        .forEach(l -> splitNameAndNum(l.split(",")));
    }

    /**
     * Accept an array of length 2 and put in the proper ArrayList
     */
    public static void splitNameAndNum(String[] arr) {
        names.add(arr[0]);
        numbers.add(arr[1]);
    }
}
```

And in Java 7:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Test {
    static ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
    static ArrayList<String> numbers = new ArrayList<String>();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("L:\\phonebook.txt")));

        String line;

        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            splitNameAndNum(line.split(","));
        }
    }

    /**
     * Accept an array of length 2 and put in the proper ArrayList
     */
    public static void splitNameAndNum(String[] arr) {
        names.add(arr[0]);
        numbers.add(arr[1]);
    }
}
```

Comment: crap I dont have Java 8. I tried the imports but it crashes when I run it. Anyways thanks for the response ill update and try again.

Comment: @TarjitSaini edited to included a simlar Java 7 solution.

Answer (score 1):

For a full functionnal (rather than imperative) solution I propose you this one :

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Object[] names = Files.lines(new File("phonebook.txt").toPath()).map(l -> l.split(",")[0]).toArray();
    Object[] numbers = Files.lines(new File("phonebook.txt").toPath()).map(l -> l.split(",")[1]).toArray();


    System.out.println("names in the file are : ");
    Arrays.stream(names).forEach(System.out::println);
    System.out.println("numbers in the file are : ");
    Arrays.stream(numbers).forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

output 
`names in the file are : 
Bin Arry
Alex Cadel
Poh Caimon
Diego Amezquita
Tai Mai Shu
Yo Madow
Caup Sul
This Guy
Me And I
Justin Thyme
Hey Oh
Free Man
Peter Piper
William Mulock
numbers in the file are : 
1110001111
8943257000
3247129843
1001010000
7776665555
1110002233
5252521551
7776663333
0009991221
1113332222
3939399339
4533819911
6480013966
9059671045`

As you can see functionnal programming is short and smart …. and easy when you're accustomed

Comment: Unfortunately my Eclipse Program comes from B.C so my computer explodes when I try your code. Thanks for the solution ill try upgrading my program lol